# castle windsor: array of complex types from config

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have a requirement to initialize a list of complex types from config.

Ideally I'd have in windsor.config a list of object definitions with all of the values for the properties defined, and have windsor initialize a new List with the objects and their values set.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a TypeConverter. The old-style documentation describes using a TypeConverter to allow a complex object to be described in Xml. The doc is [here](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/typeconverters.html).